# Strict Standards: Declaration of MySQLDb::LastId() should be compatible with Db

Tags: php

I am using article live content management scripts which is now shut-down and there is not support available.

At the top of the site showing the below error message on all pages:

`Strict Standards: Declaration of MySQLDb::LastId()` should be compatible with `Db::LastId($seq = '')` in `/home4/xxxx/public_html/xxx.com/lib/mysqldb.php` on line `29`

And also some menu bar using `ajax/responsive` not working in admin area.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function LastId in MySQLDb as below

`MySQLDb::LastId($seq = '')`

`Db` class seems to be parent class of `MySQLDb` and you have declared function `LastId` which expects 1 argument with is default value, but in child class you have overrided the same function with zero argument.
From PHP 5.3 it will show you warning in you do like above.

Comment: Thank you. But as a newbie I am not sure what to do. Can you explain me what I need to change in mysqldb.php . here I upload the mysqldb.php 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCsZx2vYf5yVmxteTdvM2xUdTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you just need to copy the declaration of `LastId` function from `Db` class to `MySQLDb` class. Thank write your code .

Comment: Most probably you need to add `$seq = ''` in the argument list of `LastId` function.

Answer (score 0):

It's mean you have to respect the parent function pattern:

```
class MySQLDb extends Db {
    ...
    public static function LastId($seq = '') {
        // your method
        // if you call the parent function, do:
        // return parent::LastId($seq)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am new to php. Can you explain me what I need to change in mysqldb.php . here I upload the mysqldb.php 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCsZx2vYf5yVmxteTdvM2xUdTQ/view?usp=sharing